# best way to create an hourly/timing javascript variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am driving nuts with this, I have to update a variable from a GET request in javascript, hourly. Then these values to be used from a different file.
Something like:

//fileA.js

```
let channel;

let getChannels = function(){
    request.get("http/...",function(result){channel = result})
}

schedule.scheduleJob('30 * * * *',getChannels)

module.exports.channel = channel;
```

//fileB.js

```
let channel = require('./fileA').channel;
console.log("hey the actual channel at this very instant is " + channel)
```

What is currently happening is that fileB does not print the channel and terminates but keeps posting the same as fileA that is, without terminate. It seems fileB only gets a reference from A and not an instant copy of the value at the moment of the request. I don't want to create a mongoDB just for that and redis does not improve much.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Juan

Comment: `require('./fileA')` executes all the code in fileA. So if something in fileA runs forever, than anything that does a `require('./fileA')` will run forever.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of just importing the value and not executing the entire code in fileA?

Comment: No? It sort of sounds like you want to run one process perpetually, fetching a new value every hour, and then you want to run another process periodically, asking the first process for the current value. So you'll need to run two separate processes and figure out a way for them to communicate. (Perhaps the simplest way would just be to have the first process write to a file that's read by the second?)

Comment: the second not perpetually but on demand, send a post rest request, the server has to do something using the values that are updated hourly, I can get post requests every milisecond or once a day, does not matter the values in A would need to be updated hourly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just creating a class out of fileA? This way fileA will not be singleton and you will have an ability to have multiple instances:

```
// file A
module.exports = function () {
  this.channel = 'none'

  schedule.scheduleJob('30 * * * *', () => {
    request.get('...', (result) => {
      this.channel = result
    })
  })
}

// file B
let Scheduler = require('./fileA')
let scheduler = new Scheduler()

console.log(scheduler.channel)
```